# Container and bottom not positioned right

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML code

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php" class="active"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="login.php" class="active"><span>Login</span></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><span>Left Menu</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="threecol">
            <div class='col3'>
                xg<br /><br />hxh<br /><br />x<br /><br />f<br /><br />h
            </div>
            <div class="col2">
                jjh<br /><br /><br />ghjh<br />x<br /><br /><br /><br />g
            </div>
            <div class='col1'>
                kgkdfh
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <p>This page  <a href="">Powered</a> by <a href="">dddddd</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and the CSS:

```
 #container {
     width: 98%;
     margin: 0 auto;
 }
 #header {
     clear:both;
     width:100%;
 }
 .threecol {
     position: relative;
 }
 .col1 {
     left: 1%;
     position: absolute;
     width: 15%;
     background-color: #eee;
 }
 .col2 {
     background-color: white;
     left: 16%;
     width: 58%;
     position: relative;
 }
 .col3 {
     left: 74%;
     top :0;
     position: absolute;
     width: 24%;
 }
 #footer {
     margin: 0 auto;
     position: relative;
     bottom: 0;
     width:100%;
     border-top: 1px solid #000;
 }
```

What I'm getting is:

1. container not in full page , there are some divs out of container
2. footer not stayed in bottom , he up to divs.

I'm lost between positioning and how to get the right result like I want. What am I doing wrong?

FOR **demo in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z28Lq/)**

Comment: Is your jsfiddle link working?

Answer (score 1):

Some advice of me, how i would do this.
I am not giving you the code but a few tips that will make you do this in no time

1. Get rid off all the position attributes in your .css
2. Use float:left to position divs next to each athor
3. Create a div with class="clear" and add to you .css code

   div.clear {
       clear:both;
       margin:0;
   }
4. Use this div everytime you have used float attribute
5. Use margins, paddings, floats

and before i forget,

body has a standaard padding in some browsers.

```
body { 
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:100%;
}
```

will take care of that

Comment: I concur with the use of floats. HOWEVER, the poster may have a specific reason for using absolute positioning! Also, do not use a clearing div except for very rare instances. Use overflow: hidden; on the container. That is more standard.

Comment: using a div for clearing is the way to go when working in a team, just to show to the rest of your team: this is where i clear. 
Every developer has is own standards, so thats personal, i gave him my advice, what i would do

Comment: i think its other way to use floats but also positioning work thought

Comment: it was nice but the footer still follow the height of div of class 2. removed positions and replaced by floats , and added clear both to footer. but footer follow the height of div2

Answer (score 1):

1) Col2 styles should be:

```
   .col2 {
    background-color: white;
    left: 16%;
    width: 58%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
   }
```

Change position to absolute and add top: 0; declaration.

2) Google sticky footer. This is very complex.

Comment: this was helpful thx but the footer if i put more code in div of class 2 it stay in its place

Comment: take a look here for footer stays up when more content http://jsfiddle.net/Z28Lq/2/

Answer (score 0):

(1 and 2 should really be separate questions, but here goes)

1:

The margins on the `<ul>/<li>` tags, and possibly also margins on the `<body>` tag will prevent your container from being full page. set `margin: 0;` on the `<ul>` and `<li>` and you should be good to go. use padding if you want it to have spacing.

Margins will push objects away from each other, they don't actually add pixel space. So if the list has a left margin and it is inside a container, then it will push the list *and the container* away from the edge of the page or other dom nodes outside the container.

the divs that are outside the container are all `position: absolute`. when something is absolute position, it doesn't belong to the parent element anymore, it floats on top of the page by itself and has no impact on the layout of the page. if you need it to be inside the container, then you can't make it position absolute.

2:

for the footer you are using position relative, which means "move this x pixels away from where it would normally be rendered", then you have bottom: 0; which means the position up by zero pixels relative to where it normally would be.

You probably want `position: fixed; bottom: 0;`.

Comment: even body is not full page , even if i make height : 100%;  <ul><li> have also their css.

Comment: no not fixed for footer, i tried absolute but the footer it stays in the middle of page

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit new to JSfiddle but here is the solution:

Sorry poor formatting:

```
 .threecol {
          overflow: hidden;
          }
 .col1 {
        left: 1%;
        float: left;
        width: 15%;
        background-color: grey;
       }
  .col2 {
        background-color: white;
        width: 58%;
           float: left;

       }
  .col3 {
     float: left;


       width: 24%;
         background-color: grey;
       }
```

Comment: with this overflow: hidden; it brokes all :) , all content disapear !

Comment: Jsfiddle link works with the latest FF. Scroll down. Anyway, I helped you more than enough. Figure it out or pay someone.